# Why can we use Error protocol as generic type?

Tags: ios, swift, generics

Why is it possible for Error protocol?
For any other protocol, we receive error

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

}

struct Test1<T> where T: SomeProtocol {

}

struct Test2<T> where T: Error {

}

let test1: Test1<SomeProtocol> = Test1() ----> Protocol 'SomeProtocol' as a type cannot conform to the protocol itself
let test2: Test2<Error> = Test2() ----> It's Ok
```

Comment: May be because Error is a specific protocole which has no requirment.

Comment: SomeProtocol also has no requirement. What did you mean?

Comment: If you use it like this ```@objc protocol SomeProtocol {``` then it will work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is just an exception in the rule. It is documented [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/7123d2614b5f222d03b3762cb110d27a9dd98e24/userdocs/diagnostics/protocol-type-non-conformance.md#exceptions):

> #### Exceptions
>
> When used as a type, the Swift protocol `Error` conforms to itself; `@objc` protocols with no static requirements can also be used as types that conform to themselves.

If it weren't for this exception, you wouldn't be able to do `Result<T, Error>` or `AnyPublisher<T, Error>` to say "some result that can be *any* error" or "a publisher that can emit *any* error".

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!